# Vba loop function range values from one sheet to another sheet if condition is matched

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

How to write the last line where if the condition is matched then the range in "master" should be equal to the content in "CST log"?

How to write that range from (Y, 2) to (Y, 35)?

```
Private Sub CSTSEARCH_Click()
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Worksheets("CST LOG").AutoFilterMode = False
Worksheets("CST LOG").Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Worksheets("CST LOG").Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
x = Sheets("CST LOG").Range("B" & Rows. Count).End(xlUp).Row
For y = 7 To x
If Sheets("CST LOG").Cells(y, 8).Value = Sheets("MASTER").Range("G6").Value Then
'Sheets("MASTER").Range("G7:G39") = Sheets("CST LOG").Cells(y, 2)(y, 35).Text
```

Comment: Are you looking to reference the cells in "CST LOG"? Or do you just want to copy and paste the values into "Master"?

Comment: when the condition is met in IF statement, then the range in sheet (CST log)  should be updated in the sheet (master). I am able to write the range in sheet (master) but unable to give the range in sheet(CST log). If i write Sheets("MASTER").cells("G7") = Sheets("CST LOG").Cells (y, 2).Text, then only one cell value is updated in sheet (master) instead of that i want full range need to be updated

Comment: Please share the screenshots of your source (`CST LOG`) and destination (`MASTER`) worksheets. Two screenshots of the destination worksheet, one for the before and one for the after, would be great. Are you aware that `G7:G39` is a single **column** with **33** cells while `.Range(.Cells(y, 2), .Cells(y, 35))` is a single **row** with **34** cells? Please include all of your code, or at least up to the line `Next y`.

Comment: HOW TO WRITE THE CODE FOR  -Range(.Cells(y, 2), .Cells(y, 34)), I AM NOT ABLE TO ATTACH THE SCREEN SHOT HERE, IF U CAN LET ME KNOW THE WHATSAPP NUMBER I CAN SHARE.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the right syntax to write a range's values to another range. This line (that you have commented) is strange to me:

```
Sheets("MASTER").Range("G7:G39") = Sheets("CST LOG").Cells(y, 2)(y, 35).Text
```

So, I tested it out and was surprised to find that it was valid syntax, but what it did was fill the cells in the range (y,2) to (y,35) with the text from the single cell G7.

So, all you need to do is change the syntax to write to the range you want.

For example, say that I have data in the range A1:A3 and I want to copy that data to the range C1:C3.  Also, everything is on Sheet1 for this example.  I can do that with this code:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

sht.Range("C1:C3") = sht.Range(sht.Cells(1, 1), sht.Cells(3, 1)).Value
```

Hopefully this should be enough guidance for you to modify the code to do what you want.